# Get count of rows returned by a locked stored procedure WITHOUT @@rowcount

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, rowcount

As part of an automation script that I'm writing in Microsoft SQL Server, I need to count the rows returned by a stored procedure, unfortunately this stored procedure is locked/encrypted and it has a `DROP TABLE` statement after the `SELECT` statement which resets the `@@rowcount` (to 0).

Is there any way to get/capture the row-count of the rows returned by that stored procedure without having to to alter the code in the stored procedure?

Comment: If the rows are returned to the client anyway, why do you need to get their count?

Comment: First statement after the select, assign @@rowcount to a variable....

Comment: What's this for? If you are just doing some adhoc manual analysis you could look at `SELECT last_rows,*
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps
JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs ON qs.plan_handle= ps.plan_handle
where ps.object_id = object_id('dbo.YourProc')` but I wouldn't use anything like that in production code

Answer (score 3):

You can INSERT...EXEC into a temp table or a table variable, then count rows from the table.

Something like this:

```
create proc rr as
select 1 aa, 1 bb union select 2, 2

declare @t table (aa int, bb int)
declare @c int

insert into @t
exec rr

select @c = count(*) from @t
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary Martirosyan,  your solution worked great for me, if case if Store Proc is expected to return large amounts of data, I guess I can use a table to store the output (instead of a Table type variable.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to capture messages when proc executes and pick the "rows affected" details from that (assuming proc returns rows once, you can add multiple returns).

try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (run_details varchar(1000)) 
INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S "Server\Instance" -Q "exec db_name.schema_name.proc_name"'
SELECT TOP 1 replace(replace(t.run_details, '(', ''), 'rows affected)', '') Rows_affected_by_proc FROM #temp t
WHERE t.run_details LIKE '(% rows affected)'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @MasoudR no, 'set nocount on' kills those messages, but OP is definitely getting the messages because it's mentioned that @@rowcount is not helpful because of the drop statement inside the proc.

Comment: @@rowcount and `NOCOUNT` are completely orthogonal. Turning off `NOCOUNT` just suppresses the rowcount sent back to the client. It doesn't stop `@@ROWCOUNT` from working

Comment: @MartinSmith right, OP is not able to use the @@rowcount only because of the drop table statement within the SP.

Comment: Thanks @Sacse, I think your approach will work, but in our organisation, we're discouraged to use / enable the "xp_cmdshell", but thanks anyway.